# Changing process input output arguments

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper, business-process-management

When creating process there is an UI for creating input/output arguments.[image: Input/output arguments]

After creation there is no way to change these. Only place where I could find this data is in process.bpmn file itself opend via external text editor. Is there a way to edit these arguments using jDeveloper?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done via structure window:

[image]